# Multiplicativity of the Euler characteristic for fibrations

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

For a Serre fibration
$$
F\to E \to B ,
$$
with $F,E,B$ having the homotopy type of finite complexes, it is known that the Euler characteristic is multiplicative:
$$
\chi(E) = \chi(F)\chi(B) .
$$
However, if we more generally assume that $B$ and $F$ are **finitely dominated** spaces, then does multiplicativity hold as well? (Recall that a finitely dominated space is a retract of a homotopy finite one.)

If true I am looking for a reference. If false, please explain.

**Added later:** it's true if the base is homotopy finite since we can take the fiberwise double suspension to obtain a fibration with homotopy finite fibers having the same Euler characteristic.  So we only need to consider the case when the base is a finitely dominated and the fibers are homotopy finite.

**Second Addition:**  I can solve the problem in general if I can solve it in the following case:  Let  $\tilde B \to B$ be a finite, regular, $n$-sheeted covering space, where $B$ is finitely dominated. Then $\chi(\tilde B) = n\chi(B)$.

(Note that $\tilde B$ is again finitely dominated, since there is a finite covering $\tilde B\times S^1 \to B\times S^1$ and by a theorem of Mather, a space $X$ is finitely dominated if and only if $X\times S^1$ is homotopy finite. But since the base $B\times S^1$ is homotopy finite, we can put a finiteness structure on the total space as well.)

**Third Addition:** The case alluded to in my "Second Addition" holds, by the second answer I gave below.

Comment: Am I mistaken? The formula you wrote is conditioned: the fibration should be orientable. This seems a consequence of Leray–Serre spectral sequence which holds for quite general spaces?

Comment: @Z.M Yes, you are mistaken.  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80326/multiplicativity-of-euler-characteristic-for-non-orientable-fibrations?rq=1

Comment: Hmm.. wait doesn't the answer to the MO question you mentioned ( https://mathoverflow.net/a/80327/184 ) still apply when F is finitely dominated?  It looks like it just uses that F has an Euler characteristic, not that it is actually a finite CW complex.  So with your added comment does that give a positive answer?

Comment: I'm confused by the "added later" comment. First of all, taking the fiberwise double suspension changes the total space -- how do you know that the new and old total spaces have the same Euler characteristic? Secondly, even granted that, it seems to me you are saying "it is true in case $X$, so we are reduced to case $X$", which is garbled. Third, if $F \to E \to B$ is a fiber sequence where $F,B$ are finitely-dominated, then does $E$ always have an Euler characteristic?

Comment: @TimCampion Let me first answer your third point: yes. Since F and B being finitely dominated will imply that E is too.

Comment: @TimCampion as to your first point:  I think so if we assume additivity of the Euler characteristic holds for pushouts of finitely dominated spaces. If $S_B E$ denotes the fiberwise suspension of $E\to B$, then $\chi(S_B(E))= 2\chi(B) -\chi(E)$ by additivity. Iterating once more gives $\chi(S^2_B(E))=\chi(E)$.

Comment: @TimCampion as to your second point, given my answer to your third one, it's clear.

Comment: @ChrisSchommer-Pries I could not extract the result from the answer to the MO question since induction on the cells will fail. I also looked at the Ponto-Shulman paper--it's written in a weird way: the title has "multiplicativity" but there is no explicit multiplicativity statement in the paper.

Comment: @JohnKlein Thanks, that clarifies my first and third questions. Regarding my second question, it seems to me that you mean to say "it suffices to consider the case where the base is finitely-dominated and the fibers are finite" but what you said is the other way around -- am I still misunderstanding? Taking the fiberwise double suspension keeps the same base but turns the finitely-dominated fiber into a finite fiber, no?

Comment: @TimCampion oh yes... thanks. It's corrected now.  By the way, the additivity assumption I made is not hard to prove.

Comment: @JohnKlein Oh that explains things. I was confused by the typo. I agree that the MO answer only seems to work if the base is a finite CW complex, but not if the base is only finitely dominated.

Comment: @ChrisSchommer-Pries more specifically: if you remove a cell from a finitely dominated space, then it might no longer be finitely dominated, right?

Comment: @ChrisSchommer-Pries But maybe there is a possible way forward here: assume more generally that the base $B$ has finite Betti numbers. Then the Euler characteristic is defined. Perhaps one can do a kind of transfinite induction on a cell structure to obtain the result from that MO answer?  My reasoning is that if $B$ has a finite Betti numbers then removing a single cell from $B$ results in a space $B_0$ having finite Betti numbers.

Comment: Am I wrong that one essentially needs the rational homology of $B$ and $F$ to be bounded above and finite dimensional in each grading. If true then does being finitely dominated guarantee any of these?

Comment: @user51223 Yes it does.

Comment: So, then would it suffice just to work rationally and answer your question in the rational setting. It then looks to me that a Serre spectral sequence argument together with conditions in my previous comment guarantees the multiplicativity of the Euler characterisitic. Hence, the question really becomes when given an $X$ such as you mention, there always exists $Y$ that retracts onto $X$ and has the aforementioned properties?!

Comment: @user51223 How do you apply the Serre spectral sequence? I imagine that one could take the Euler characteristic of the (sheaf) cohomology instead of the homology, for which Serre spectral sequence seems to hold without assumptions on anything. In this case, $\mathcal H^t(F)$ are only locally constant sheaves, and seemingly, one has to assume something like if $\mathcal F$ is local system of $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces (with value $V$) on $B$, then the Euler characteristic of $R\Gamma(B,\mathcal F)\in D(\mathbb Q)$ is equal to the product $\chi(B)\dim(V)$.

Comment: Note that if $B$ is a retract of $B'$, then the whole fiber sequence $F \to E \to B$ is a retract -- as a fiber sequence -- of a fiber sequence $F \to E' \to B'$. We even have $E' = E \times_B B'$ and $E = E' \times_{B'} B$. So we even have the whole Serre spectral sequence for $F \to E \to B$ sitting as a retract of the Serre spectral sequence for $F \to E' \to B'$. In our case, we can take $B'$ to be finite, so the conclusion is known for the latter spectral sequence. This feels pretty close to a solution to me...

Comment: @TimCampion. I observed that too, but  I don't think it will work: you can take $B \times S^1$ for $B'$. Then $B'$ is homotopy finite (cf. Wall), but its Euler characteristic is trivial.

Comment: @TimCampion see the "Second Addition" to my post. I've reduced the problem to a that of a regular finite covering space.

Comment: @ChrisSchommer-Pries see the "Second Addition" to my post. I've reduced the problem to a that of a regular finite covering space.

Comment: If you have solved it, it would be nice if you could write the arguments in more detail. In particuler the reduction to the case of covers and the Leray-Serre spectral sequence argument - it sounds hard to get rid of the $\pi_1$-action

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I will. Just not today. Over the weekend perhaps.

Comment: Can you make a more refined statement? For example, define $w(X)\in K(\pi_1(X))$ to combine the Euler characteristic and the Wall finiteness obstruction. Can you identify the image of $w(E)$ in $K(B)$? in $K(E)$?

Comment: @Z.M To show that the Euler characteristic of the cohomology of a local system is the product of the Euler characteristic of the cohomology, the normal approach is to pull back to a cover of $B$ by finitely dominated spaces on which the system is trivialized. This is not possible. But you can probably arrange a hypercover, by combining the cover for $B\times S^1\to B$ and the cover of $B\times S^1$ by cells. This requires care because at first the hypercover by a higher dimensional object appears to require infinite degrees, but they don't, really.

Comment: I think that [Pedersen-Taylor 1978](https://people.math.binghamton.edu/erik/bibliography/wallfibr.pdf) prove that the total Wall invariant satisfies $w(E)=\chi(F)w(B)$, and thus that $\chi(E)=\chi(F)\chi(B)$.

Comment: @BenWieland  yes, that does it! Thanks.

Comment: @BenWieland : is this what they prove ? From reading it it seems like it's not $\chi(F)$, but $\chi(p)$. There is a $\pi_1$-action there. Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Right, $\chi(p)$ is an element of $K(B)$ that might not be a number. It becomes $\chi(F)$ when forgetting the $\pi_1(B)$ action.

Comment: @BenWieland : but why can you forget the $\pi_1(B)$-action ? To get $\chi(B)$ out of $\sigma(B)$ (in the paper's notation), don't you have to push forward along $\mathbb Z[\pi_1(B)]\to \mathbb Z$ ? (it seems like the paper doesn't mention $w(B)$, only the wall invariant itself, but maybe I'm misunderstanding something)

Comment: @BenWieland I had to temporarily delete my proof. It is now back. I think there is a gap between the Pedersen and Taylor result and the deduction that the Euler characteristic is multiplicative for fibrations.  Let's consider the case of finite covers $p: E\to B$ The problem is that $\sigma(B) \chi(p)$ arises as a tensor product of two $\Bbb Z[\pi]$-modules: $P \otimes H_0(F)$ where $P$ is the Wall finiteness obstruction of $B$.  Here $H_0(F) = \Bbb Z[F]$ has a $\pi$-action. We need to know $P \otimes_{\Bbb Z[\pi]} H_0(F) \cong P \otimes_{\Bbb Z[\pi]} H_0(F^t)$ with ($F^t$ = trivial action).

Comment: @BenWieland I think my proof below (if correct) fills the gap. The only thing I am a bit shaky on is the proof of them Lemma in the case when $\pi$ is finite.

Comment: @JohnKlein : As I pointed out below the first answer, I agree with your point about Pedersen-Taylor's result, and as I pointed out below the second answer, I believe the lemma is wrong for finite groups (and hence in general). I also believe I have a proof of the multiplicativity where this point is precisely adressed, but it uses a bit of machinery, I'll try to write it down today

Answer (score 7):

Note Added March 1, 2022:

I now think there is a gap in deducing multiplicativity of the Euler characteristic from the Pedersen-Taylor result on the finiteness obstruction.  I think the argument I give in my other answer more-or-less fills that gap.

---

Ben Wieland has provided a reference which answers my question.

Pedersen, Erik Kjaer; Taylor, Lawrence R.
The Wall finiteness obstruction for a fibration.
Amer. J. Math. 100 (1978), no. 4, 887–896.

The authors identify the image in $K_0(\Bbb Z[\pi_1(B)])$ of the Wall finiteness obstruction $\sigma(E) \in K_0(\Bbb Z[\pi_1(E)])$. The Euler characteristic is the image of this class $K_0(\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: Why is the image of $\chi(p)$ in $G_0(\mathbb Z) \cong K_0(\mathbb Z)$ just $\chi(F)$ ?

Comment: The image of $\chi(p)$ under in $G_0(\mathbb Z)$ seems to exactly be a line in the Serre spectral sequence for the fibration

Answer (score 5):

I have already written a lot, but Oscar Randal-Williams's comment below John Klein's second answer seems to really simplify the matter, so I decided to add an answer to that effect. I can remove any of the answers I have written if somehow they're "obfuscating the view" or anything.

This argument is just a simplification, that bypasses Pedersen-Taylor's result, and also the need for Swan's other theorem (suggested by Oscar) that $\tilde K_0(\mathbb Z[\pi])$ is finite for a finite group $\pi$ (I think the proof is harder, although I might be mistaken here). The argument is therefore due to Oscar and John in this respect, this is just my write-up of it.

Namely, as in all other answers reduce to the case of a finite covering space $p: E\to B$. Letting $F$ denote the fiber, and $Q$ the (finite) image of $\pi_1(B)\to Aut(F)$, let $f: B\to BQ$ denote the corresponding classifying map.

Define the following functor from perfect $\mathbb Z[\Omega B]$-modules to $\mathbb Q$-modules: $P\mapsto B_!( (P\otimes_\mathbb Z \mathbb Q) \otimes_\mathbb Q C_*(F;\mathbb Q))$.

The observation is that $C_*(F;\mathbb Q)$, as a $\mathbb Z[\Omega B]$-module, is of the form $f^* C_*(F;\mathbb Q)$, so this is $\mathrm{colim}_{BQ} f_!((P\otimes_\mathbb Z\mathbb Q)\otimes_\mathbb Q f^*C_*(F;\mathbb Q))\simeq \mathrm{colim}_{BQ} f_!(P\otimes_\mathbb Z\mathbb Q) \otimes C_*(F;\mathbb Q)$ (where $\mathrm{colim}_{BQ}$ is derived)

In other words, this functor factors as $Perf(\mathbb Z[\Omega B])\to Perf(\mathbb Z[Q])\to Perf(\mathbb Q[Q])\to Perf(\mathbb Q)$, but the most important part is the first part.

Indeed, $Q$ is finite, and so on $K$-theory, $K_0(\mathbb ZQ)\to K_0(\mathbb QQ)$ lands in the image of $K_0(\mathbb Q)$ (under the "induction" morphism) : this is (as far as I know) a theorem of Swan's (specifically, theorem 4.2 from his book "K-theory of finite groups and orders")

Now if $P= \mathbb Q[Q]^n$ is a free $\mathbb Q[Q]$-module, $\mathrm{colim}_{BQ}(P\otimes_\mathbb Q C_*(F;\mathbb Q)) = \mathrm{colim}_{BQ}(P\otimes_\mathbb Q C_*(F^{triv}; \mathbb Q)) = P_{hQ}\otimes_\mathbb Q C_*(F; \mathbb Q)$.

In particular, on $K$-theory, this composite has the same effect as $\mathrm{colim}_B (-)\otimes_\mathbb Q C_*(F;\mathbb Q)$, and so it sends the trivial coefficient system $\mathbb Z$ to $C_*(B;\mathbb Q)\otimes_\mathbb Q C_*(F;\mathbb Q)$, which of course is another name for $\chi(B)\chi(F) \in \mathbb Z\cong K_0(\mathbb Q)$.

But this map also sends this trivial coefficient system to $C_*(E;\mathbb Q)$, which is also another name for $\chi(E)\in \mathbb Z\cong K_0(\mathbb Q)$.

This proves the claim.

Comment: Is it essential to take $Q$ to be the image of $\pi_1(B)\to\operatorname{Aut}(F)$ rather than $Q:=\operatorname{Aut}(F)$? Is the reduction to coverings essential? I mean, for example, is the group $\operatorname{Aut}(F)$ still finite enough when $F$ is a compact object?

Comment: @Z.M the $Q$ part doesn't seem to be essential; on the other hand $Aut(F)$ is definitely not finite enough for a general compact (even finite!) space $F$, so that part seems essential

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand correctly. It seems that the finiteness is mainly used in the step of invoking Swan's result. For example, I don't know what happens if I run this argument for general fiber sequences instead of coverings.

Comment: @Z.M yes, that's exactly  where it is used. But this part was the key point - if you look at Pedersen's result, or at John's other answer (or my other answer) you'll see that this is the main problem : getting rid of the $\pi_1$-action somehow. In all cases, the argument is basically to use finiteness, so it really seems essential. If you run this argument for general fiber sequences, it doesn't work, so that is what happens :)

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I wanted to say general fiber sequences with fibers being compact, so there is finiteness, just no discreteness, namely, run the argument as far as possible without the extra step to pass to coverings.

Comment: @Z.M : No, the automorphism group/space of a compact space is almost always far from finite.  Think of $(S^1)^2$ for instance, its automorphism group splits as $(S^1)^2 \times GL_2(\mathbb Z)$ (as a space) so its $\pi_0$ is infinite. Typically, it won't even locally be a compact space - so you can't really run the argument.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an argument that the
Euler characteristic is multiplicative for fibrations
$$
F\to E \to B
$$
where $F$ and $B$ are finitely dominated and $B$ is connected.
Without loss in generality, we may assume that $E$ is also connected.

**Step 1.** The first fact is that for a homotopy pushout
$\require{AMScd}$
$$
\begin{CD}
X_{01} @>>>  X_1\\
@VVV @VVV \\
X_0 @>>> X
\end{CD}
$$
of finitely dominated spaces, the Euler characteristic is additive.  This follows from the Mayer-Vietoris sequence
using the Betti number definition of Euler characteristic. I won't include the proof here; I think the argument is easy.

**Step 2.** An immediate corollary is that
$$
\chi(S_B E) = 2\chi(B) - \chi(E)\, 
$$
where $S_B E\to B$ is the fiberwise suspension.  Iterating once more, we get
$$
\chi(S^2_B E) =  \chi(E)\, .
$$
But the fibers of $S^2_BE\to B$ are homotopy finite with the same Euler characteristic as
the fibers of $E\to B$, and so this enables us to reduce to the case when $E\to B$ has homotopy finite fibers.

**Step 3.**  The action defines a homomorphism
$$
\pi_1(B) \to \text{GL}(H_\ast(F;\Bbb Z/2))
$$
and therefore a finite covering space $\tilde B \to B$.  The base change (pullback) of the fibration $E\to B$ to $\tilde B$ yields a new fibration
$\tilde E\to \tilde B$ which is **orientable** in the sense of the Serre spectral sequence and the latter fibration has fiber $F$. Moreover, both $\tilde E$ and $\tilde B$ are again finitely dominated (since $B$ is and the fibers are).  It follows from Spanier's book (p. 481) that $\chi(\tilde E) = \chi(\tilde B)\chi(F)$.

**Step 4.** By the previous step, it is sufficient to show that the Euler characteristic is multiplicative for $n$-sheeted covering spaces
$$
E\to B
$$
with $B$ finitely dominated.  Here $F$ is a discrete set of cardinality $n$.

For this, I will appeal to Waldhausen's functor $X\mapsto A(X)$, where $A(X)$ is the finitely dominated flavor of the algebraic $K$-theory of spaces.

**Step 5.** Recall that $A(X)$ can be defined as the $K$-theory of the Waldhausen category of equivariant based spaces
$$
R(\ast;H)\, ,
$$
where $H$ is a topological group model for the loop space of $B$, i.e., $BH \simeq B$.  Objects of $R(\ast;H)$ are based spaces with $H$-action that are $H$-finitely dominated, in the sense that there are retracts of up to homotopy of finite objects (a finite object is one which is built out of finitely many free cells $D^k\wedge(H_+)$.)

Note that
$$
\pi_0(A(B)) = K_0(\Bbb Z[\pi_1(B)]),
$$
and the class of $S^0 \in R(\ast;H)$ is identified with the unreduced version of Wall's finiteness obstruction.

**Step 6.** We may identify $p:E\to B$ as induced by the homomorphism
$G\to H$ of suitable topological groups. Then one has a **pushforward**
and  **transfer** functors
$$
R(\ast;H) \overset{p^!}\to R(*;G) \overset{p_*}\to R(*;H)
$$
in which
$p^!(U) = U$ (i.e., restrict the action) and $p_*(Z) = Z\wedge_G (H_+)$.

It follows that
$$
p_*p^!(U) \cong U\wedge (F_+) ,
$$
where the target is given the diagonal $H$-action.

*Claim:* Let $F^t$ denote the finite set $F$ but with the trivial $H$-action (made cofibrant, i.e., $F^t = |F|\times EH$). Then $F_+,F^t_+\in R(\ast;H)$ define the same $K$-theory classes after pushforward to $R(\ast,e)$.

**Sketch proof of Claim:** With respect to the homomorphism $H\to e$,
the objects $F,F^t $ push forward to $E_+$ and $(B\times F)_+$
in $R(\ast;e) = R(\ast)$.
If $B$ is a finite complex, then the
Additivity Theorem and induction along the skeleta of $B$ show that
$ E_+ $ and $(B\times F)_+ $ define the same $K$-theory class.

If $B$
is finitely dominated, of dimension $r$ say, then by an argument of Wall,
there is a finite complex $K$ of dimension $r-1$ and an $(r-1)$-connected map   $K\to B$ which we can take to be a cofibration by
adjusting $B$ up to homotopy equivalence.  Furthermore, One can find such a map $K\to B$ such that
the relative homology $H_\ast(\tilde B,\tilde K;\Bbb Z)$ is trivial except in degree $r$, where $\tilde B\to B$ is the universal cover
and $\tilde K \to K$ is the pullback to $K$, and in degree $r$, we have that $P := H_r(\tilde B,\tilde K;\Bbb Z)$ is a finitely generated projective $\Bbb Z[\pi]$-module (with $\pi = \pi_1(B)$).
Note that $(-1)^rP \in K_0(\Bbb Z[\pi])$ is the Wall finiteness obstruction of $B$.

As $K$ is finite, by the above one has that $E|K$ and $K\times F$ define the same class in $\pi_0(A(\ast)) = K_0(\Bbb Z)$.

Furthermore, using the fact
that $\tilde B$ is $1$-connected, there a cofiber sequence of spaces
with $\pi$-action
$$
\tilde E_{|K} \to \tilde E \to (\tilde B/\tilde K) \wedge F_+
$$
(since the base change of $E\to B$ along $\tilde B \to B$ is a trivializable cover). Since $K$ is finite, $E_{|K}$ and $K\times F$
define the same class in $\pi_0(A(\ast))$. By additivity, it will be enough to show that
$$
H_r((\tilde B/\tilde K) \wedge_{\pi} F_+) = P\otimes_{Z[\pi]} \Bbb Z[F_+]
$$
is isomorphic to $P \otimes_{\Bbb Z[\pi]} \Bbb Z[F^t]$ as a $\Bbb  Z$-module.

To complete the proof of the claim, it is enough to establish the following:

**Lemma:** Suppose that $P$ is a finitely generated projective left $\Bbb Z[\pi]$ module. Then the finitely generated free $\Bbb Z$-modules
$$
P \otimes_{\Bbb Z[\pi]} \Bbb Z[F] \quad \text{ and }\quad 
P \otimes_{\Bbb Z[\pi]} \Bbb Z[F^t] 
$$
have the same rank.

*Proof of Lemma*  (After Oscar Randall-Williams).
In the above, to talk about the tensor product, we have regarded $P$ as a right module
using the involution $g\mapsto g^{-1}$ of $\pi$.

Let $\Pi = \text{iso}(F)$, the automorphisms of
the set $F$. Then $\Pi$  is finite. Moreover, one has a homomorphism
$\pi \to \Pi$ and we can define
$$
P' := P\otimes_{\Bbb Z[\pi]} \Bbb Z[\Pi]
$$
Then $P' \otimes_{\Bbb Z[\Pi]} \Bbb Z[F] = 
P\otimes_{\Bbb Z[\pi]} \Bbb Z[F]$ and this enables to assume at the outset that $\pi$ is finite.

So assume that $\pi$ is finite.

Consider the homomorphisms
$$
\rho,\rho^t: K_0(\Bbb Z[\pi]) \to K_0(\Bbb Z)
$$
defined by $\rho(P) = P\otimes_{\Bbb Z[\pi]} \Bbb Z[F]$, and
$\rho^t(P) = P\otimes_{\Bbb Z[\pi]} \Bbb Z[F^t]$.

It will be enough to show that these two homomorphisms coincide.

They certainly coincide for $P$ a f.g. free module of rank one and therefore for any f.g. free module.

Using Swan's Theorem that the reduced group
$\tilde K_0(\Bbb Z[\pi])$ is a torsion group (with $\pi$ finite), it follows that
$\rho = \rho^t$ in general.
$\square$.

Let $c: \pi_0(A(B)) \to \pi_0(A(\ast))$ be the map induced by the pushforward $B\to \ast$.

Hence, by the claim, the composition
$$
\begin{CD}
\pi_0(A(B)) @> p^! >> \pi_0(A(E)) @>p_\ast >> \pi_0(A(B))
@> c >> \pi_0(A(\ast)) = \Bbb Z
\end{CD}
$$
is identified with multiplication by $\chi(F)$ in the sense that
it is given by
$$
U \mapsto U_{H}\wedge F^t_+ \, .
$$
where $U_H$ is the reduced Borel construction.

On the other hand, if we take the pushforward of
$$
p_\ast p^!(S^0) = F_+
$$
in $R(\ast;e)$ (where $e$ = trivial group), we obtain $(F_+)\wedge_H *_+ = E_+$, and this will give the Euler characteristic $\chi(E) \in \pi_0(A(\ast)) = \Bbb Z$.

If we put the above facts together, we see that the composition
$$
\begin{CD}
\pi_0(A(B)) @> p_*p^!>> \pi_0(A(B)) @>c >> \pi_0(A(\ast)) = \Bbb Z 
\end{CD}
$$
has the property that it maps the class of $S^0$ to both $\chi(E)$ and $\chi(F)c([S^0])$. But $c([S^0]) = \chi(B)$, so we are done.

Comment: Why is each $B_i/D_i/S_i$ finitely dominated ? Or rather, why can you choose $B'$ so as to ensure that ? (There are certainly choices of $B'$ that do not have this property)

Comment: @MaximeRamzi you are right. I have to see if I can repair that part of the argument.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I think I have fixed it.

Comment: Isn't this a counterexample to your lemma in the case of a finite group $\pi$ ? Take $M= \mathbb Q$ with the trivial $\pi$-action (which is projective rationally)  then the coinvariants of $\mathbb Q[F]$ are smaller than those of $\mathbb Q[F^t]$. More generally, the action need not be free on $M$ in general.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi   Ooops. You're right.

Comment: I think the lemma is true if you don't try to "simplify" by working over $\mathbb{Q}$. The functions $|\pi| \cdot rk_\mathbb{Z}(- \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[\pi]} \mathbb{Z})$ and $rk_\mathbb{Z}(-)$ induce homomorphisms $K_0(\mathbb{Z}[\pi]) \to \mathbb{Z}$ which agree on free modules, so by Swan's theorem that $\tilde{K}_0(\mathbb{Z}[\pi])$ is finite when $\pi$ is a finite group it follows that they agree on all projective $\mathbb{Z}[\pi]$-modules.

Comment: @OscarRandal-Williams thanks. If correct, that would fix my argument.

Comment: It seems to me that with this argument one can simply then apply Pedersen's result: calling $f: K_0(\mathbb Z[\pi_1B]) \to K_0(\mathbb Z)$ the projection map, we have that $f(\chi(p)\cdot -)$ and $f(\chi(F)\cdot -)$ also agree on free modules

Comment: It also seems like in this case the rational argument works, because the rationalization of projective $\mathbb Z[\pi]$-modules is free, by another theorem of Swan's (which I think is easier to prove)

Comment: @MaximeRamzi  So, do you believe my line of argument now?

Comment: @JohnKlein : somehow (cf. my answer :D ) this surprises me a lot, but it seems like it, yes

Comment: @JohnKlein : I added another, much simpler answer than my previous one based on these comments. I must admit that I am really surprised, but it seems to work. Let me know if you want me to delete any of my answers (for clarity and room :) )

Comment: @MaximeRamzi  No, please keep them up!

Answer (score 1):

$$\newcommand{\Sph}{\mathbb S}
\newcommand{\THH}{\mathrm{THH}}
\newcommand{\Sp}{\mathrm{Sp}}$$

The answer is that Euler characteristics *are* multiplicative. I can't adress the question of a reference, though, because I don't know one.

Let me point out a few things: as you point out, I think the result does not quite follow from Pedersen-Taylor's paper, essentially for the reason that $\chi(p)$ is very different from $\chi(F)$ and there is a priori no reason you can "forget the $\pi_1(B)$-action" (or at least this reason should be added to the proof - but you seem to agree that this is a gap, so I won't comment further on this).

Your other answer has what I believe to be a gap, namely I think your lemma is wrong for finite groups.

Now, about the proof. I will outline a proof below that uses three ingredients : 1- a THH approach to traces; 2- the free-loop transfer and its comparison with THH transfer; 3- a result of Linnell's on the Bass trace conjecture (I learned it from a paper of Berrick-Hesselholt's, and one can make a simpler proof using TC and the Bökstedt-Hsiand-Madsen description of TC of spherical group rings). Of these, 1- is an artifact of my personal predilections, although I'm not sure how to get rid of it; 2- is not essential (I will use it in an essential way in the proof, but I also know a different, somewhat simpler argument that doesn't use it : the reason I don't outline this simpler one is that it relies on work in progress - if you are interested I would prefer to talk about it in private); and 3 is, I believe, essential, and essentially the core of the proof.

The argument goes roughly as follows: As you suggest, reduce to the case of finite *Galois* covers (you did not specify this, but your argument produces a Galois cover). Identify $\chi(E)$ in terms of $\THH$, and use the comparison between free loop Becker-Gottlieb transfer and THH-transfer to compare this to $\chi(F)$ : in principle, there should be some Lefschetz numbers of the monodromy action of $\pi_1(B)$ on $H_*(F)$ that appear rather than barely $\chi(F)$, but the Linnell-Hesselholt result allows you to get rid of these monodromies.

This proof may seem complicated, but I think it will be clear at the end that some complication is necessary, see the **Note** in **Step 4**. Of course it is not a precise argument, so maybe an easy argument can be found, but I think this is unlikely.

**Step 0**: Clearly $B$ is assumed to be connected, and we may assume that $E$ is connected too.

**Step 1** : reduction to Galois covers. John already outlined this, but for convenience (and also because, even though the proof is the same, I make a stronger claim), let me recall the proof. The Euler characteristic of $F$ can be computed using $H_*(F;\mathbb Z/2)$ (or $\mathbb Z/p$ for any prime $p$), and it is easy to prove the result if the action of $\pi_1(B)$ on these is trivial, using the Serre spectral sequence. In particular, letting $\tilde B\to B$ be a finite cover corresponding to the kernel of $\pi_1(B)\to GL(H_*(F;\mathbb Z/2))$, and $\tilde E$ the pullback of $E$ to $\tilde B$, we find $\chi(\tilde E) = \chi(\tilde B)\chi(F)$, so because $\tilde E\to E, \tilde B\to B$ have the same number of sheets, it suffices to prove that for either one, $\chi(\tilde X) = n \tilde X$, $n$ being the number of sheets. Note that the kernel of $\pi_1(B)\to GL(H_*(F;\mathbb Z/2))$ is of course normal in $B$ so $\tilde B\to B$ is a Galois cover. $\tilde E\to E$ is pulled back from it, so it is Galois too; so we reduced to Galois covers.

**Step 2** : $\chi(E)$ in terms of THH. Let $X$ be finite spectrum. I claim that applying $\THH$ to the morphism $\Sp^\omega\overset{X\otimes -}\to \Sp^\omega $ yields the morphism $\chi(X) : \Sph\to \Sph$ , where I use $\otimes$ for the smash product of spectra. I will abuse notation and write functors as $\Sp\to \Sp$ to avoid having to write $^\omega$ every time, but this means I will need to justify why my functors preserve compacts.

This is a fairly well-known statement, I can expend on it if needed, but I'll take it for granted for now.

**Step 3** : For a finitely dominated space $X$, observe that the functor $X^* : \Sp\to \Sp^X$ taking a spectrum to the constant parametrized spectrum over $X$ with that value preserves compacts - this is precisely because $X$ is finitely dominated, so that homotopy limits over $X$ preserve filtered colimits.

It therefore induces a morphism on $\THH$, and by the Goodwillie-Jones isomorphism (I never know the actual name, someone should tell me what it is), we have $\THH( (\Sp^X)^\omega) = \THH(\mathrm{Perf}(\Sph[\Omega X])) = \THH(\Sph[\Omega X]) = \Sigma^\infty_+ LX$, where $L$ denotes the free loop space (I'm assuming $X$ is connected, to identify parametrized spectra over $X$ with $\Sph[\Omega X]$).  This morphism is therefore a morphism $\Sph\to \Sigma^\infty_+ LX$, which corresponds to an element $f_X \in \pi_0\Sigma^\infty_+ LX \cong \bigoplus_{[\gamma]\in \pi_1(X)/conj} \mathbb Z\cdot [\gamma]$, where I use brackets $[\gamma]$ to denote the conjugacy class of $\gamma$ in $\pi_1$ (or the free homotopy class of a loop).

This $f_X$ is therefore a finite sum of the form $\sum_i n_i[\gamma_i]$, where I take pairwise distinct $[\gamma_i]$'s.

**Warning** : It might sound "obvious" that the only $\gamma_i$ that shows up is the trivial loop. Hopefully, this is true, but it is not obvious, and as far as I know, not known so far. As I explain below, this statement is equivalent to Bass' trace conjecture.

**Step 4**:  Relating to Bass' trace conjecture. This $f_X$ is defined in terms of $\THH$, so one way to study it is to relate it to $K$-theory. Indeed, the trace map $K\to \THH$ is natural, so we have a commutative square $$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}K(\Sph) @>>> K(\Sph[\Omega X]) \\
@VVV @VVV \\
\THH(\Sph) @>>> \THH(\Sph[\Omega X]) \end{CD}$$

This diagram, on $\pi_0$, becomes
$$\begin{CD}\mathbb Z = K_0(\mathbb Z) @>>> K_0(\mathbb Z[\pi_1 X]) \\
@V{id}VV @VVV \\
\mathbb Z = \THH_0(\mathbb S) @>f_X>> \bigoplus_{\pi_1(X)/conj}\mathbb Z = \mathrm{HH}_0(\mathbb Z[\pi_1(X)]\end{CD}$$

In particular, as the left vertical map is surjective, $f_X$ is in the image of the trace map $K_0(\mathbb Z[\pi_1X])\to \mathrm{HH}_0(\mathbb Z[\pi_1(X)])$. This is exactly the map that Bass' trace conjecture is about, namely:

**Conjecture** : Let $G$ be a group. The trace map $K_0(\mathbb Z[G])\to \mathrm{HH}_0(\mathbb Z[G]) \cong \bigoplus_{G/conj}\mathbb Z$ lands entirely in the summand corresponding to the neutral element of $G$.

**Note, not necessary for the proof**: The map $K_0(\mathbb S)\to K_0(\mathbb S[\Omega X])$ sends $1$ to the (unreduced) Wall finiteness obstruction of $X$. Because free modules over $\Sph[\Omega X]$ *are* sent to the summand of the neutral element of $\pi_1(X)$, and because any element of the reduced $K_0(\mathbb Z[\pi_1(X)])$ can be realized by some finitely dominated space, Bass' trace conjecture is *equivalent* to the statement that only the trivial loop shows up as one of the $\gamma_i$'s for all $X$. In particular, I will not claim that this is the case. Note, however, that if $X$ is finite, i.e. Wall's finiteness obstruction vanishes (in reduced $K$-theory), then only the trivial loop shows up.

Bass' trace conjecture is open, but some things are known about it:

**Theorem** ([Lin, Lemma 4.1], [BH, Theorem A]): Let $G$ be a group, and $g\in G$ an element such that $K_0(\mathbb ZG)\to \mathrm{HH}_0(\mathbb ZG)$ hits the summand corresponding to $g$. There exists an integer $m\geq 1$ such that for all $s\geq 1$, $g$ and $g^{s^m}$ are conjugate.

In particular, the $\gamma_i$'s that show up in $f_X$ have this property.

The core of the proof is in :

**Corollary** : Let $X$ be a finitely dominated space and write $f_X = \sum_i n_i[\gamma_i]$ as above. The $\gamma_i$'s vanish in any finite quotient of $\pi_1(X)$.

This is clear, as the image of $\gamma_i$ in the finite quotient has the same property, and has finite order.

**Step 5** : A big diagram. Return to our situation: $p: E\to B$ is a finite Galois cover, with fiber $F$ a finite set.

Consider the following commutative diagram (there are diagonal arrows so I cannot use AMScd unfortunately, which is why I used a picture - hopefully it's readable enough, sorry for the inconvenience):

[image]

I use the following notation: for a map of space $f$, $f^*$ is the restriction along $f$ for parametrized spectra, and $f_!$ its (derived) left adjoint; and if $f: X\to *$ is the projection to a point, I write $X^*$ (resp. $_!$) for $f^*$ (resp. $f_!$).

From this description, it should be clear why both triangles commute. Furthermore, all functors involved preserve compact objects : indeed, their right adjoints preserve filtered colimits, either because they are of the form $f^*$, or because they are of the form $f_*$ (the right adjoint of $f^*$) for some $f$ with finitely dominated fibers.

In particular, I can apply $\THH$ to it, and get a commutative diagram.

**Step 6** : The $\THH$-diagram.

It looks like (sorry, I had the same issue, I hope it's readable) :

[image]

The maps $f_E,f_B, \THH(p^*)$ are there by definition. The others follow from the following general claim:

**Claim** : Let $f:X\to Y$ be a map of spaces. The induced functor $f_!: \Sp^X\to \Sp^Y$ induces $\Sigma^\infty_+ Lf: \Sigma^\infty_+ LX\to \Sigma^\infty_+ LY$ on $\THH$.

This is not too hard to prove, and I think fairly well-known too. If needed, I can also add details about it (if it helps: I only need this statement on $\pi_0$ anyway !).

**Important observation** : the middle composite is $\THH$ applied to the middle composite, i.e. $\THH$ applied to $\Sp\overset{E^*}\to \Sp^E\overset{E_!}\to \Sp$, i.e. to $\Sp\overset{E\otimes -}\to \Sp$. Therefore, the middle composite is given by $\chi(E)$, by **Step 2** above.

**Step 7**: Understanding $\THH(p^*)$.

To state the theorem, let me just make an observation: $p : E\to B$ is a finite covering space, therefore so is $Lp: LE\to LB$. In particular, this map has a Becker-Gottlieb transfer, which I will denote by $(Lp)^!$.

**Theorem** ([LM, Corollary 1.5]): Let $E\to B$ be a finite covering space. With respect to the identification $\THH((\Sp^X)^\omega)\simeq \Sigma^\infty_+ LX$, we have that $\THH(p^*)$ is identified with $(Lp)^! : \Sigma^\infty_+ LB\to \Sigma^\infty_+ LE$.

**Corollary** : In the above diagram, the vertical composite is $\Sigma^\infty_+ Lp\circ (Lp)^! : \Sigma^\infty_+ LB\to \Sigma^\infty_+ LB$. In particular, it is given by "multiplication by $\chi($fiber)$.

**Warning** : it is tempting to stop here, but as I will explain below there is a small subtlety, and this is where the Linnell-Hesselholt result comes in. A first subtlety is that in general, $LB$ is disconnected, and so the multiplication by "$\chi($fiber$)$" depends on the component under consideration.

**Step 8** : Putting things together.

By the **Important observation** in **Step 6**, the middle composite of the diagram is $\chi(E)$. Because the bottom triangle commutes, one can write this composite as right-down-up instead of righ-right, and then up-down-down-up, because the top triangle commutes.

Going up gives us $f_B = \sum_i n_i[\gamma_i]$, then down-down is multiplication by $\chi(\mathrm{fib}_{\gamma_i})$, where I let $\mathrm{fib}_{\gamma_i}$ denote the fiber of $LE\to LB$ at the loop $\gamma_i$.

By **Step 4**, each $\gamma_i$ vanishes in $\pi_1(B)/\pi_1(E)$ (which is a finite quotient of $\pi_1(B)$, as $\pi_1(E)$ is normal in $\pi_1(B)$, and $E\to B$ is a finite cover). In particular, one can compute this fiber to be exactly $\pi_1(B)/\pi_1(E)$.

Here's the argument:

Because $E\to B$ is a Galois cover, letting $H\triangleleft G$ denote the corresponding normal inclusion, we have a homotopy pullback

$$\begin{CD}E@>>> * \\
@VVV @VVV \\
B @>>> B(G/H) \end{CD}$$

which remains a pullback after applying $L$. Now taking the fiber over $\gamma_i$, as $\gamma_i$ vanishes in $L(B(G/H))$ (more precisely: the composite $\{\gamma_i\}\to LB \to L(B(G/H))$ is homotopic to $L(*\to B(G/H))$), we can just take the outer pullback, which is $\Omega (LB(G/H), triv)$. For any group $K$, $\Omega(LBK, triv) = K$.

This proves the claim, and in particular the Euler characteristic of the fiber is $|G/H| = \chi(F)$ regardless of the $\gamma_i$, so that at the end of the day, the composite up-down-down sends $1$ to $\sum_i n_i\chi(F)[\gamma_i]$, and then going up one last time sends all loops to $1$, so up-down-down-up sends $1$ to $\sum_i n_i \chi(F)$.

So $\chi(E) = \sum_i n_i \chi(F)$. But $\sum_i n_i$ only depends on $B$ (the $n_i$'s are the ones appearing in $f_B$), so we can apply this to the cover $B\to B$, and we find $\sum_i n_i = \chi(B)$.

Therefore, $\chi(E) = \chi(B)\chi(F)$, as claimed, and we are (finally!) done.

**Conclusion** : The point is that in Pedersen's paper, $\chi(p)$ alone cannot be related to $\chi(F)$, it's exactly by using also $B$ that one gets to $\chi(F)$. Now this fact uses strong results about Bass' trace conjecture, and it seems like an elementary proof cannot explain this kind of "cancellation".

But maybe I am wrong. At least, I think this is a proof - of course it would be better if a more elementary one existed.
(I mentioned that I knew a simpler proof, but it still uses the Linnell-Hesselholt result)

**References** :

[BH] : Berrick-Hesselholt, *Topological Hochschild homology and the Bass trace conjecture*

[Lin] : Linnell, *Decomposition of augmentation ideals and relation modules*

[LM] : Lind-Malkiewich, *The transfer map of free loop spaces*

Comment: It will take time for me to digest this, but thanks for your write up. I am surprised that there appears to be no elementary proof.